# Zombie game in JS

Tags: javascript, pixel, offset

i have a little bit problem with my application. Im trying to make the game where zombies come from right side to the left side. They moving already, also i can kill them with mouse click but i cant find a method how can i put lethal line where they gonna die. I tried to do offset but it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```js
const game_window = document.querySelector('.game-container')
const score_window = document.querySelector('.score')
const hp = document.querySelector('.hp')
let points = 0;
class Game {
  constructor(monster_height, monster_width) {
    this.monster_height = monster_height
    this.monster_width = monster_width
    this.declare()
  }

  declare() {
    this.new_monster
  }

  create_monster() {
    this.new_monster = document.createElement('div')
    this.new_monster.classList.add('monster')
    game_window.appendChild(this.new_monster)
  }

  monster_click() {
    let monsters = document.querySelectorAll('.monster')
    monsters.forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        game_window.removeChild(el)
        this.score()
      }.bind(this));
    });
  };

  monster_move() {
    console.log(this.new_monster);
    this.new_monster.style.transform = "translateX(-1500px)"
  }

  score() {
    points += 10
    score_window.innerText = points;
  }

  health() {

  }

}


letsPlay = new Game(50, 50)

setInterval(() => {
  letsPlay.monster_move()
}, 500);

setInterval(() => {
  letsPlay.create_monster()
  letsPlay.monster_click()
  letsPlay.health()

}, 1000);
//500
//1000
```

```html
<div class="game-container"></div>
<span class="score"></span>
<span class="hp"></span>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For your question, we're going to need a little more info and code. What do you mean by "a lethal line"? Can you also share the HTML and CSS that goes along with this, as that'll likely affect the answer. Ideally, if you hit the "JavaScript/HTML/CSS Snippet" button (looks like paper with <> on it) and put the parts in there, you can get it running in the browser which will make it a lot easier to help.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Can you please make that a [mcve]?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code. Lethal line i mean the line on the screen. I would like to div with zombie destroy one of my health point :)

```js
const game_window=document.querySelector('.game-container')
const score_window=document.querySelector('.score')
const hp=document.querySelector('.hp')
let points=0;
class Game{
    constructor(monster_height, monster_width){
        this.monster_height=monster_height
        this.monster_width=monster_width
        this.declare()
    }

    declare(){
        this.new_monster
    }
    
    create_monster(){
        this.new_monster=document.createElement('div')
        this.new_monster.classList.add('monster')
        game_window.appendChild(this.new_monster)
    }

    monster_click(){
        let monsters=document.querySelectorAll('.monster')
        monsters.forEach( el => {
            el.addEventListener('click', function(){
                game_window.removeChild(el)
                this.score()
            }.bind(this));
        });
    };

    monster_move(){
        console.log(this.new_monster);
            this.new_monster.style.transform="translateX(-1500px)"
    }

    score(){
        points+=10
        score_window.innerText=points;
    }

    health(){
       
    }

}


letsPlay=new Game(50, 50)

setInterval(()=>{
    letsPlay.monster_move()
}, 500);

 setInterval(() => {
    letsPlay.create_monster()
    letsPlay.monster_click() 
    letsPlay.health()
    
 }, 1000);
//500
 //1000
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image:url('images/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height:100%;
    cursor: crosshair;
}

.game-container{
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top:25%;
}

.monster{
    width:6%;
    height:170px;   
    transition-duration: 3s;
    background-image: url('images/zombie.png');
    background-position: center;
    position:absolute;
}
.scoreNav{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.score {
    width:20%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
    font-size:50px;
    color:white;
    margin:1% 0 0 1%;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 200%;
}

.health{
    display:Flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 15%;
    height:70px;
    background-color:black;
    position:relative;
    right:5%;
}

.score, .health{
    border-radius:12%;
}
.hp{
    position: relative;
    top:15%;
    background-image: url("images/hp.jpg");
    background-image: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="scoreNav">
        <div class="score"></div>
        <div class="health">
            <div class="hp"></div>
            <div class="hp"></div>
            <div class="hp"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="game-container">



        
    </div>

    <script src="logic.js"></script>
</body>
```